# Is there a way to see all of my Facebook activity of the (very long ago) past easily?

Tags: facebook

I've been trying to trace something out using Facebook and I was all the way back by about 8 months and accidentally clicked the wrong thing and now I'd have to start all over (mind you, it took about 2 hours to get to 8 months).

Is there any easier way of seeing all of my Facebook statuses and other activity from the past, easily? (As in, without the whole scroll-click-scroll-click thing.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, very easily. Facebook recently implemented a feature that allows you to download your entire profile, just click 'learn more" on your account page (see screenshot). https://register.facebook.com/editaccount.php

It will compile your profile, photos, statuses, videos, etc and email you when it's ready. The download manager then makes you pass some verification questions in which you identify people (you're supposed to know) who are tagged in your friends' photos.

[image: Download your informaiton - learn more]

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've managed to do this is is by playing with their [api](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user) in the browser.

On the api page scroll down to the Connections table and click on feed link - this will bring back you last 50 or so feeds from your wall.

In the URL add this (Change 100 to the number of items you want back)

```
?limit=100
```

right after https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed part of the url.

it should look somehting like this:

https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?limit=100&access_token={some rather long string}

It's not perfect but hopefully should get you close to what you want.

Comment: any help on how to generate the access_token?

Answer (score 1):

Click on the Settings icon.
Click on **Privacy Settings**.
Click on the **Privacy** tab.
Click on "***Use Activity Log***".
done!