# How do I search for old items I posted in my own Facebook timeline?

Tags: search, facebook, facebook-timeline

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Better way to search the Facebook activity log / timeline?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/26727/better-way-to-search-the-facebook-activity-log-timeline)

I was just trying to look up something on my own timeline (specifically, the last time I had jury duty). Unfortunately, the native Facebook search feature seemed to be completely useless for this. I couldn't even get it to show me a post from 24 hours ago.

The Facebook search feature seems to only works for public content, and doesn't seem to allow restricting results to just my own content. My privacy settings are generally set to friends-only, and I don't allow public searching of my timeline. I do, however, think I should be able to search my *own* content.

Is there a way to search my own content with Facebook either natively with the standard Facebook web app or with a trustworthy/secure app or add-on?

Comment: Have you tried the browser search (`Ctrl/Cmd + F`)?

Comment: @Alex, that only works for the part of the timeline that is currently showing on the page. I'm looking for something that lets me search through my entire history.

Comment: [related question](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/26727/19350)

Answer (score 2):

I have an answer to your question.

If you're looking for a particular string of characters, just search it like you would search in the top search box (as if you were going to search for a friend or page on Facebook).

Then when you get your results scroll down through the friend and page results, and Facebook will have searched through your timeline for what you typed in. It will be under "Posts By Friends". Below the results you can click on "See More Results", which is right above "Web Results" from Bing.

As a sidenote, make sure when you search you click on the magnifying glass, that is not pressing ENTER (because that may take you to the first search result).

Let me know how this goes for you.

Comment: Darn, I thought that would work, but when I click on "See more Results" under "Posts by Friends", I get zero results (and I know there should be at least two hits). It still seems like it's only searching among publicly available content as opposed to all content visible to me.

Comment: Sorry! I tested it with a post I knew I had saw and it was in the search results. Maybe what you're looking for has been removed by who posted it.

Comment: I'm talking about things *I* posted in *my own* timeline. They are definitely not deleted. If I test your method with things I've posted in the last week (and I know they're still there), it still doesn't work.