# How do I search for articles/posts on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline, facebook-search

How do I search for articles/posts on Facebook? I want to search in my friend's timeline but the top navigation search only limits to people, places and things.

Comment: Related: [Better way to search the Facebook activity log / timeline?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/26727/22453)

Answer (score 2):

As to my knowledge you can't. I've tried this a few times, and the only way was to just scroll through until I found what I was looking for.