# How do you search through a friend's Facebook profile for a specific post?

Tags: facebook

Is there a way to search through a friend’s Facebook profile for a post you remember some of the words of? I've tried using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> but it appears only part of the posts get loaded each time you view a profile. Is that right? I've tried scrolling really far down in the history but wasn't able to find it and the post was made recently.

Comment: Possible clone of http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/53399/38959

Answer (score -1):

You might want to try http://archivedbook.com/ which I found to be a great tool for finding auto archived posts in Facebook.